# Stop C# Window Service when SQL connection error occured in timerCallback function

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am new to thread programming and recently one issue is assigned to me in which threading is used. I need your help to resolve the issue in best way.

There is a Window Service which create thread and function StartScheduler is called. This function further create a thread and function StartJob is called. In StartJob function TimerCallback object is created and function LoadandRunJob function is called every 50 seconds to load and executes jobs.

Note: Each thread specified above is created in separate class. So there are multiple classes.

My requirement is to stop window service when sql server connection is broken and error occur in function LoadAndRunJob.

**Sample Code**

```
private void StartJob ()
{
    _timerCallback = new TimerCallback(LoadAndRunJob);

    //Schedule the requery to happen every 50 seconds.
    _timer = new Timer(_timerCallback, null, 50000, 50000);
}

private void LoadAndRunJob(Object state)
{

    try
    {
        //Here is the code to load and execute the jobs   
    }
    catch
    {
        //Require code here to stop the service
    }
}
```

One thing I tried is to raise event after catching the error. And stopped service in event handler. I don't know whether it is the best way to handle it or not.

Comment: This is something I would discuss with people at work to be honest. There are questions to ask, for example why do you need to stop the service instead of logging and alerting someone? Services like that usually try to do a job several times before quitting. What if other jobs work and one doesn't?

Comment: Actually when SQL connection is broken then service is not able to do any task, but it is still shown as running. So client wants that service should be stopped if SQL connection broken due to any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
catch
{
   new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("YourServiceName").Stop();
}
```